# How to compare values of generic types?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, icomparable

How do I compare values of generic types?

I have reduced it to a minimal sample:

```
public class Foo<T> where T : IComparable
{
    private T _minimumValue = default(T);

    public bool IsInRange(T value) 
    {
        return (value >= _minimumValue); // <-- Error here
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'.

What on earth!? `T` is already constrained to `IComparable`, and even when constraining it to value types (`where T: struct`), we still can't apply any of the operators `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `==` or `!=`. (I know that workarounds involving `Equals()` exist for `==` and `!=`, but it doesn't help for the relational operators).

So, two questions:

1. **Why** do we observe this weird behaviour? What keeps us from comparing the values of generic types which are *known* to be `IComparable`? Doesn't it somehow defeat the entire purpose of generic constraints?
2. How do I resolve this, or at least work around it?

(I realize there are already a handful of questions related to this seemingly simple problem - but none of the threads gives an exhaustive or workable answer, so here.)

Comment: For the record, this is now possible in C# 10, since interfaces can now contain static methods (thus allowing the overloading of operators)

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`IComparable` doesn't overload the `>=` operator. You should use

```
value.CompareTo(_minimumValue) >= 0
```

Comment: Great, this works (and explains it, of course) - thanks a lot! But it's a bit unsatisfying, and leaves the question: *Why* doesn't IComparable overload the comparison operators? Is this a conscious and deliberate design decision, with a good reason - or something that was overlooked in the design of the framework? After all, 'x.CompareTo(y) >= 0' is less readable than 'x >= y', no?

Comment: I definately get your point. I guess the problem is that operators are static which means they cannot fit in an interface. I will not judge whether this is a good choice or not, but I tend to think that methods with proper names are easier to read than operators when types are non primitive; this is a matter of taste though.

Comment: @gstercken: I attempted to address that question in my answer, though it is all speculation :)  Though +1 on this, because it is concise.

Comment: @gstercken: One problem with `IComparable` overloading the comparison operators is that there are situations where `X.Equals(Y)` should return false, but `X.CompareTo(Y)` should return zero (suggesting neither element is larger than the other) [e.g. an `ExpenseItem` may have a natural ordering with respect to `TotalCost`, and there may be no natural ordering for expense items whose cost is the same, but that doesn't mean every expense item that costs $3,141.59 should be considered equivalent to every other item that costs the same.

Comment: @gstercken: Fundamentally, there are a number of things that `==` could logically mean.  In some contexts, it's possible for `X==Y` to be true while `X.Equals(Y)` is false, and while in other contexts `X==Y` could be false while `X.Equals(Y)` is true.  Even if operators could be overloaded for interfaces, overloading `<`, `<=`, `>` and `>=` in terms of `IComparable<T>` might give an impression that `==` and `!=` would also be overloaded in such terms.  If C# had, like vb, disallowed the use of `==` on class types for which it was not overloaded that might not have been too bad, but...

Comment: ...alas C# decided to use the token `==` to represent both an overloadable equality operator and a non-overloadable reference-equality test.

Comment: Could you please update answer with C#11 generic numeric types solution?

Answer (score 43):

If `value` can be null the current answer could fail. Use something like this instead:

```
Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, _minimumValue) >= 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I needed this for some extension methods I was working on. See below.

Comment: OK, got it. I wasn't constraining `T` to `IComparable`. But your tip got me over the hump nevertheless.

Answer (score 35):

**Problem with operator overloading**

Unfortunately, interfaces cannot contain overloaded operators.  Try typing this in your compiler:

```
public interface IInequalityComaparable<T>
{
    bool operator >(T lhs, T rhs);
    bool operator >=(T lhs, T rhs);
    bool operator <(T lhs, T rhs);
    bool operator <=(T lhs, T rhs);
}
```

I don't know why they didn't allow this, but I'm guessing it complicated the language definition, and would be hard for users to implement correctly.

Either that, or the designers didn't like the potential for abuse.  For example, imagine doing a `>=` compare on a `class MagicMrMeow`.  Or even on a `class Matrix<T>`.  What does the result mean about the two values?;  Especially when there could be an ambiguity?

**The official work-around**

Since the above interface isn't legal, we have the `IComparable<T>` interface to work around the problem.  It implements no operators, and exposes only one method, `int CompareTo(T other);`

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx

The `int` result is actually a tri-bit, or a tri-nary (similar to a `Boolean`, but with three states).  This table explains the meaning of the results:

```
Value              Meaning

Less than zero     This object is less than
                   the object specified by the CompareTo method.

Zero               This object is equal to the method parameter.

Greater than zero  This object is greater than the method parameter.
```

**Using the work-around**

In order to do the equivalent of `value >= _minimumValue`, you must instead write:

```
value.CompareTo(_minimumValue) >= 0
```

Comment: Ah, right - makes sense. I forgot that interfaces in C# can't overload operators.

Answer (score 7):

```
public bool IsInRange(T value) 
{
    return (value.CompareTo(_minimumValue) >= 0);
}
```

When working with IComparable generics, all less than/greater than operators need to be converted to calls to CompareTo. Whatever operator you would use, keep the values being compared in the same order, and compare against zero. ( `x <op> y` becomes `x.CompareTo(y) <op> 0`, where `<op>` is `>`, `>=`, etc.)

Also, I'd recommend that the generic constraint you use be `where T : IComparable<T>`. IComparable by itself means that the object can be compared against anything, comparing an object against others of the same type is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `value >= _minimValue` use `Comparer` class:

```
public bool IsInRange(T value ) {
    var result = Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(value, _minimumValue);
    if ( result >= 0 ) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}
```

Comment: Wny introduce the use of a `Comparer` when there is already a generic constraint that `T` must implement `IComparable`?

Comment: @Fredrik generic constraints tend to build up. I agree with omitting them here.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, one needs to explicitly use the CompareTo method.  The reason that one cannot use interfaces with operators is that it is possible for a class to implement an arbitrary number of interfaces, with no clear ranking among them.  Suppose one tried to compute the expression "a = foo + 5;" when foo implemented six interfaces all of which define an operator "+" with an integer second argument; which interface should be used for the operator?

The fact that classes can derive multiple interfaces makes interfaces very powerful.  Unfortunately, it often forces one to be more explicit about what one actually wants to do.

Comment: I don't think MI isn't any more a problem with overloaded operators as it is with regular methods.  They are just funny syntax for methods.  So you could solve that problem by using the same rules would be used to resolve them as regular methods on interfaces.  One of the C# design goals was to have it be somewhat familiar to C++ programmers, and overloaded operators were abused to hell and back in that language.  I'm guessing the designers preferred named methods which force you to give some sort of documentation for the intent of those methods.

Answer (score 1):

`IComparable` only forces a function called `CompareTo()`. So you cannot apply any of the operators that you have mentioned

Answer (score -1):

I was able to use Peter Hedberg's answer to create some overloaded extension methods for generics. Note that the `CompareTo` method doesn't work here, as type `T` is unknown and doesn't present that interface. That said, I'm interested in seeing any alternatives.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void RemoveDuplicates<T>(this List<T> Instance)
{
  Instance.RemoveDuplicates((X, Y) => Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(X, Y));
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void RemoveDuplicates<T>(this List<T> Instance, Comparison<T> Comparison)
{
  Instance.RemoveDuplicates(new List<Comparison<T>>() { Comparison });
}

[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void RemoveDuplicates<T>(this List<T> Instance, List<Comparison<T>> Comparisons)
{
  List<bool> oResults = new List<bool>();

  for (int i = 0; i <= Instance.Count - 1; i++)
  {
    for (int j = Instance.Count - 1; j >= i + 1; j += -1)
    {
      oResults.Clear();

      foreach (Comparison<T> oComparison in Comparisons)
        oResults.Add(oComparison(Instance[i], Instance[j]) == 0);

      if (oResults.Any(R => R))
        Instance.RemoveAt(j);
    }
  }
}
```

**--EDIT--**

I was able to clean this up by constraining `T` to `IComparable(Of T)` on all methods, as indicated by OP. Note that this constraint requires type `T` to implement `IComparable(Of <type>)` as well.

```
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public void RemoveDuplicates<T>(this List<T> Instance) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    Instance.RemoveDuplicates((X, Y) => X.CompareTo(Y));
}
```